# Qt Bluetooth stuck when connecting to Classic Bluetooth Device

Tags: c++, linux, qt, bluetooth, bluetooth-peripheral

I am currently trying to read out Bluetooth Signals from peripherals using classic BT to control my Qt application. Later on I might use a small BT joystick but for now I am trying to connect to the buttons on my paired headphones.

I have previously

1. ..scanned for remote devices via the `QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent`, which returned the `QBluetoothDeviceInfo` of my headphones.
2. ...scanned for the services on that device using the `QBluetoothServiceDiscoveryAgent`, which returned `QBluetoothServiceInfo` with `QBluetoothUuid::AV_RemoteControl`
3. ...added a socket which should connect to the device, like so:

   ```
   socket0 = new QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::L2capProtocol);

   connect(socket0, &QBluetoothSocket::stateChanged, this , &BluetoothController::socketStateChanged);
   connect(socket0, &QBluetoothSocket::readyRead, this, &BluetoothController::readSocket);
   connect(socket0, &QBluetoothSocket::connected, this, &BluetoothController::serverConnected);
   connect(socket0, &QBluetoothSocket::disconnected, this, &BluetoothController::serverDisconnected);
   connect(socket0, QOverload<QBluetoothSocket::SocketError>::of(&QBluetoothSocket::error),
       this, &BluetoothController::serverError);


   QBluetoothAddress address = info.device().address();
   QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   socket0->connectToService(address, QBluetoothUuid::AV_RemoteControl, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
   ```

   At this point the socket state changes to *ConnectingState*, does not through an error, but also does not not trigger my `readyRead()` function.

I am new to Bluetooth and may be misunderstanding the concept of how connecting exactly works, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

PS.: I am working on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 and the application log also puts out:

> qt.bluetooth.bluez: Missing CAP_NET_ADMIN permission. Cannot determine
>   whether a found address is of random or public type.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run your software as a non-root user. The Bluetooth protocol stack for Linux checks two capabilities, which are required for operations like ones mentioned in your error log — `CAP_NET_RAW` and `CAP_NET_ADMIN`. Capabilities are an alternative to "all or nothing" approach with privileged user (root). This gives more fine-grained control over permissions to unprivileged user so it can gain only a part of root's privileges. For more details, read `man 7 capabilities`.

There're several techniques for leveraging capabilities, one of them are file capabilities. You can achieve the desired effect with `setcap(8)` like this:

`sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip' yourapplication`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to use the command on my application with no success. The error persists and on top of that I get additional errors in other parts of my application


_Failed to load plugin '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstqt5videosink.so': /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5: symbol _ZNK11QFontEngine10glyphCacheEPKvNS_11GlyphFormatERK10QTransform version Qt_5_PRIVATE_API not defined in file libQt5Gui.so.5 with link time reference
Failed to create qtquick2videosink. Make sure it is installed correctly_

Comment: That has to do with gstreamer plugin, probably due to incompatibility. It loads shared object dynamically, yet fails to find a necessary symbol. Has nothing to do with original issue.